# WebResource accept() not working in release(run) mode java over jetty using Jersey framework

Tags: java, jetty, jersey

**I am trying to connect to the Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) server using the Jersey framework over a jetty server.**
It works well in debug mode but fails when I run it normally. Here is the code which makes a connection to GCM:

```
WebResource r = client.resource("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
response = r.accept(
           MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
           header("Content-Length", ""+sPostData.length()).
           header("Authorization", "key="+sAPIKey).
           header("Keep-Alive", "false").
           entity(sPostData).
           post(String.class);
System.out.println("response:"+response);
```

Control never comes to last line.
**It works WELL in debug mode , there is problem with release(run) mode using jetty server**
Can anyone make a suggestion about why this is happening?
Please provide your thoughts over it.